# EditText - Cap words with no suggestions?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to make some EditText support Cap words AND disable suggestions

Any combination I tried not working:

```
edittext.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD
```

This one removes the spell checking but doesn't make cap words

```
edittext.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS or InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
```

This one make cap words but doesn't remove the spell

How to do it?

Comment: java has `or` too? I thought you should use `|`.

Comment: @Afshin it is Kotlin

Comment: you can use `android:inputType="textCapWords|textNoSuggestions"` in xml

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried put in xml `android:inputType="textCapSentences|textVisiblePassword"`?
This should work as I remember.

Comment: I need cap words, not sentences. Furthermore I need to make it progrmatically